# Trouble with these sentences, subject-verb confusion and difficult words?

Tags: meaning

I'm a little clueless with these two sentences right here.

> 景気判断は前月のまま据え置き、消費増税後の駆け込み需要の反動減は「和らぎつつある」とした。ただ反動減が長期化すれば、「景気下押しのリスク」となる可能性を初めて指摘。
>
> 政府は７～９月期には自動車の生産・販売や住宅建設などが反動減から脱して景気が上向くことが、来年１０月に消費税率を予定通り１０％に再引き上げするのに欠かせないとみている。

Some of the words I've tried scouring the dictionary but to no avail, 消費増税後の**駆け込み需要**? I don't quite understand how 駆け込み relates to 需要 in the sentence.
Here's another one: 反動減
I know 反動 means reactionary, but what does the 減 do here? I tried looking up for it and nothing showed up. What does it mean in the sentence? How would you translate it?

Also, does the 政府 here correspond to 再引き上げする or みている? Or is みている simply a grammatical pattern I'm unaware of?

For context:

> 反動減の長期化懸念　景気判断据え置き　８月経済報告
>
> 内閣府は２６日、８月の月例経済報告を公表した。景気判断は前月のまま据え置き、消費増税後の駆け込み需要の反動減は「和らぎつつある」とした。ただ反動減が長期化すれば、「景気下押しのリスク」となる可能性を初めて指摘。反動減からいつ脱するかが、景気回復のカギとなりそうだ。
>
> 個別項目では、企業収益は上場企業の４～６月期の業績が伸び悩んだことを受けて、「改善に足踏みがみられる」と判断を引き下げた。
>
> 個人消費は「一部に弱さが残るものの、持ち直しの動きがみられる」と判断を据え置いた。大雨など天候不順で百貨店や家電量販店の売り上げが落ちたが、景気全体への影響は限定的だとしている。住宅建設は「減少のテンポが緩やかになっている」と判断を引き上げた。項目によって、判断の上げ下げにばらつきが目立っている。
>
> ４～６月期の国内総生産（ＧＤＰ）の実質成長率は増税の影響でマイナス６・８％（年率）と落ち込んだ。政府は７～９月期には自動車の生産・販売や住宅建設などが反動減から脱して景気が上向くことが、来年１０月に消費税率を予定通り１０％に再引き上げするのに欠かせないとみている。
>
> 甘利明経済再生相はこの日の会見で、「７～９月期に力強く回復することが大事だ。反動減が底打ちし、回復に向かう動きをしっかりみていきたい」と述べ、反動減の長期化に懸念を示した。

Comment: if you go to http://www5.cao.go.jp/keizai3/getsurei-e/2014aug.html, you can see what I believe to be the government's published translation of the document you are getting that from.

Comment: Do you know this tool: http://language.tiu.ac.jp/? Very useful for studying texts like those.

Answer (score 1):

「[駆]{か}け[込]{こ}み」, in this context, means "last-minute"; therefore, 「駆け込み[需要]{じゅよう}」 means "last-minute demand".  If you are doing something at the last minute, you will have to 駆ける = "run fast", won't you?

「[反動減]{はんどうげん}」 means a "reactionary downturn".

In April of 2014, the Japanese consumption tax rose from 5% to 8%, causing a last-minute surge in demand in many industries because many individuals and corporations wanted to save money by purchasing goods before the tax hike took place on April 1.  After April, however, we naturally had a reactionary downturn in demand of goods because we had stocked up pretty good before April.  「減」 = the downturn

On to the next sentence 「政府は７～９月期には自動車の生産・販売や住宅建設などが反動減から脱して景気が上向くことが、来年１０月に消費税率を予定通り１０％に再引き上げするのに欠かせないとみている。」.

Subject of sentence: [政府]{せいふ} = the Japanese Government

Main verb: みている = To observe (for judgement).  There sure is the quotative 「と」 there.  「～～とみている」 =  "~~ is the way someone sees it".

What is the administration's judgement?  (What is the "~~" part?)  It is 「７～９月期には自動車の生産・販売や住宅建設などが反動減から脱して景気が上向くことが、来年１０月に消費税率を予定通り１０％に再引き上げするのに欠かせない」.

(I am not translating any part of it unless you show us your own attempt.)