# What does 「ものと見られます」 mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, phrases

From a news segment in Persona 5:

> 切り札として招いた社長が事故で死亡し、 改革の遅れが懸念されているものと見られます。

What does ものと見られます mean? Upon looking it up, I [found](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A8%E6%80%9D%E3%82%8F%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B-%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A8%E8%A6%8B%E3%82%89%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B-mono-to-omowareru-meaning/) that it means "to think; to suppose; it is believed/expected that ~", which makes sense to me, but what doesn't make sense is how to parse this phrase in my head.

What exactly is もの in this phrase?

When would you use と見られる instead of what makes sense to me, と思われる？

Comment: Dup or related [What does ものと見て, mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/69713)

Comment: @sundowner this is very helpful, but I'm still not sure what もの adds to the phrase, or if it's even necessary at all. is ものと見る/思う a set phrase?

Comment: In the particular sentence, it is simply optional and adds virtually nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(もの)と見られる and (もの)と思われる mean almost the same thing, but 見る is generally preferred in news articles, especially those related to police investigations.

- [What does とみる mean here?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/64877/5010)
- [Meaning of 見る in 「１日から２日は見て」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/74638/5010)

Note that this れる is not passive but something called [自発](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/97507/5010).

---

もの is a completely different issue, and it's much tricker to explain. [ものだ has lots of usages and nuances](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/43083/5010) and they are generally hard to translate into English. Here, もの is optional, but I think it basically adds a nuance like "that's how it is" or "this is what's (generally) expected". Please see the links in the following answer:

- [What would be the function of the というものだ in this context?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/82293/5010)
- [What is the use of ものでしょうか in this context? 「今から治療して間に合うものでしょうか？」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/100908/5010)

Answer (score 1):

Your interpretation is correct: ものと見る in this context means "it is believed/expected that ~". Sometimes, it's still hard to interpret a sentence as a whole, even if you understand every piece of expression in it, so let me try and help you:

> 遅れが懸念されているものと見られます。

"(...) it is believed that there is a worry that there might be a delay."

Comment: Is もの optional in this construct? I'm not sure what it's adding.

Comment: @user3856370 Please read the answer from naruto.